# Google Sheet API 4 - can we access files created by App engine application in Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

We are creating files using the following authentication

```py
self.GOOGLESHEETS_SCOPES = 
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

self.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
self.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(self.GOOGLESHEETS_SCOPES)
self.credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(self.GOOGLESHEETS_SCOPES)

self.service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=self.credentials)
```

Can we access these files using the Google Drive GUI? I cannot find any documentation that confirms or denies this possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the regular Sheets service you can create the file with [the create method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) of the API and access it in the Drive UI.

Comment: When you say Drive UI - how do I set this up? Remember the google sheet is created by Google sheet api 4 by an app engine application (not by an user).

Comment: I meant GUI - if you're creating a Sheet using the Google Sheets API v4 then the created files are accessable in the GUI.